# Что такое двухфазовый коммит?

Tags: веб-служба

Что такое двухфазовый коммит?

Контекс фразы:

> SOAP поддерживает ACID (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation,
>   Durability). REST поддерживает транзакции, но не один из ACID не
>   совместим с двухфазовым коммитом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Двухфазовая фиксация** (commit) - это **протокол** для **распределенной системы** который обеспечивает возможность принять или откатить изменения для всей системы в целом.

В **нераспределенной системе** (в которой присутствует одна компонента) вы можете организовать транзакции используя **однофазную фиксацию**, но в распределенной системе ошибка/нарушение ограничения (препятствующая фиксации изменений) может произойти в любой части (компоненте) системы. Поэтому на первой фазе все компоненты системы подтверждают, что изменение может быть зафиксировано, а вторая фаза уже непосредственно фиксирует/откатывает изменения.